# Configure IntelliJ reformat for double curly braces in yaml

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml, kubernetes-helm

YAML files sometimes contain templated values in double curly braces, e.g. when used by Helm to configure Kubernetes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

The formatting as I have shown it is what I want, and what is standard in Helm files: a space within the inner pair of curly braces, but not *between* the two curly braces on each side.

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to respect this formatting style? As far as I can tell, the options (under `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > YAML > Spaces`) are either:

- Within code braces `YES`, which would produce `{ { .Release.Name } }`
- Within code braces `NO`, which would produce `{{.Release.Name}}`

Comment: Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @pgoldste did you make a ticket? I can't seem to find one but I don't want to create a duplicate.

Comment: I did not, please do go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone ends up here like me, this is solved by installing the following two plugins from JetBrains:

- Kubernetes Plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10485-kubernetes
- Go Template Plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10581-go-template

After installing, the auto formatting respected the following style without further configurations:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I installed both plugins "Kubernetes" and "Go Template" but I still had the issue. The solution that worked for me with IntelliJ was:

- Disable the YAML bundled plugin;
- Restart IntelliJ;
- Re-enable the YAML bundled plugin.

...and the IDE formatter does not put a space between double curly braces anymore.